# React Native: mapping though a mounted non-null value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

The component is set up in a way that it mounts and is then assigned a value when I try to use it in my render, it is null for the first mount before the value is assigned to it. But I need to map through the array I get, so I check if the value is null and if not, I map.. but it seems to crash the app.

```
class EventCalendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        };

        this.handleGetEvents = this.handleGetEvents.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.handleGetEvents();
    }

    handleGetEvents() {
        this.props.getEvents();
    }

    render() {
        const { events } = this.props;
        console.log(events);
        return (
            ...                    {events ?
                                    <ScrollView>
                                        {events.map((event, index) => (
                                            <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Event', event)}>
                                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15, paddingRight: 15, borderColor: '#ddd', borderWidth: 1 }}>

                                                    ...
                                                            </View>
                                                        </View>
                                                    </View>
                                                </View>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        ))}
                                    </ScrollView>
                                    : []
                                };
                            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon and the end...

So...

```
</ScrollView>
: []
};
```

Becomes...

```
</ScrollView>
: []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What the other guy said, but also instead of using a ternary, why not just go:

`{!!events && events.map ...`

but also instead of testing for the truthiness of events, why not test explicitly if it's an array or not with:

`{Array.isArray(events) && ...`

EDIT: Elaborating for a user:

```
{Array.isArray(events) &&
  <div>
     {events.map(event => <span>{event.name}</span>)}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: @user1803096 could you elaborate and show more code?

Answer (score 0):

```
{events == null ? <ScrollView></ScrollView>:
                                <ScrollView>
                                    {events.map((event, index) => (
                                        <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Event', event)}>
                                            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15, paddingRight: 15, borderColor: '#ddd', borderWidth: 1 }}>

                                                ...
                                                        </View>
                                                    </View>
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    ))}
                                </ScrollView>}
```

Comment: here :

    events == null ? <ScrollView></ScrollView>:

you can replace with:

    events == null ? null :